# How to test if the linux crypto module is right?

Tags: linux-kernel, cryptography

I'm writing a module supporting hardware accelerator like x86-64 Intel AES. But this is for MIPS platform.
Is there any simple way to test if my module is right or not? For example, I would like to provide a plain
text/key/IV as input in kernel space, then I will get encrypted text and compare it with the one encrypted
by openssl in user space. If it's the same, this means my module is right. Do we have a similar way? Do
I need to write another kernel module to verify or there is an existing one? Thank you!

Comment: At the very minimum I would try and include NIST test vectors for the modes you want to support. I'd also urge you to test your own edge cases, i.e. the boundaries that are in your own code, that's often forgotten and not present in any known test cases.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks. I plan to use IPSec to test first.